# Why is it stopping when it is not supposed to

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I am creating a space Invaders game and have asked the stackoverflow community about it. But this time things are a bit more complicated. There is no visible error but the window just pops up and closes which is not supposed to happen. I created a loop and for some reason it isnt working

```
import pygame
import os
import time
import random
pygame.font.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750, 750 
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

# Load Images
RED_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_red_small.png"))
GREEN_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_green_small.png"))
BLUE_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_blue_small.png"))

# Player Ship
RED_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_yellow.png"))

# Lasers
RED_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_red.png"))
GREEN_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_green.png"))
BLUE_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_blue.png"))
YELLOW_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_yellow.png"))

# Background
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "background-black.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, x, y, health = 100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y    
        self.health = health
        self.ship_img = None
        self.laser_img = None
        self.lasers = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.x, self.y, 50, 50))x


def main():
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    level = 1
    lives = 5
    main_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)


    ship = Ship(300, 650)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def redraw_window():
        WIN.blit(BG, (0,0))    
        #  draw text
        lives_label = main_font.render(f"Lives: {lives}", 1, (255,255,255))
        level_label = main_font.render(f"Level: {level}", 1, (255,255,255))

        WIN.blit(lives_label, (10, 10))
        WIN.blit(level_label,(WIDTH - level_label.get_width() - 10, 10))

        ship.draw(WIN)

    pygame.display.update()

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        redraw_window()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
main()
```

I tried reviewing my code but I couldn't see anything.

Comment: Your window does not pop up and go away unless you do not have your assets where you say they are.  Instead, it runs forever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your infinite `while` loop doesn't do anything, and runs forever doing that.  Your loop needs to be:

```
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        redraw_window()
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
```

Comment: The question says the window opens and closes immediately. If it's an infinite loop, shouldn't the window stay open?

Comment: The question says that, but that's not what the code does.  I tried it.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work is it working for you

Comment: Yep.  Remember that indentation is absolutely critical.